# Mongodb setup issue in AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, redhat, fedora

I am following mongodb guide https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/ and trying to install on AWS EC2.

When i am trying the following command

```
echo "[MongoDB]
      name=MongoDB Repository 
      baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64 
      gpgcheck=0 enabled=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/yum/repos.d/mongodb.repo
```

I am getting the following error message.

> tee: /etc/yum/repos.d/mongodb.repo: No such file or directory

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the MongoDB documentation is outdated, or just has a typo, but I think the correct file/directory is `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo`.

So the full command would be:

```
echo "[MongoDB]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
```